# Need help with Oracle Query

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have one Employee Table  with the fields - EmpId, EmpName, Salary.
Table Contain 8 record. Now I want to get 3rd highest salary.
can you please provide query for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from (select * 
        from employee 
        order by salary desc) 
where rownum = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (select DISTINCT salary from employee order by salary desc) where rownum = 3;
```